# syntax 'T<...>(...)' is impossible. What's the next best thing?

Tags: c++, constructor, c++17

I have a type

```cpp
class foo {
public:
    foo(int);

    template <typename T, typename U>
    foo(T, U);

    template <typename T, typename U>
    foo(std::inirializer_list<T>);

    // or other different constructors.
};
```

explicitly calling an exact overload of a constructor is impossible.
syntax `foo::foo<int>(int());` (`class<tmpl_params>::ctor<tmpl_params>(args)` just like the syntax of a static member function) is `ill-formed` (and on top of that `foo(int)` isn't a template). Same story with any other overloaded version of a constructor.

is there a way (even a hacky one) to explicitly force the compiler to use one overloaded version of a constructor instead of any other?

There's automatic type deduction, but that's an implicit way.

Comment: There is no way. Actually, even template non-constructors suffer from the same issue in a more limited number of cases: for example, try forcing the variadic function to be called with 1 argument in the following example: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0b81c23397b063de

Comment: The next best thing is to rely on template argument deduction, SFINAE, and overload resolution rules. If you can't do that, then declare some of your constructors to take a tag type for disambiguation. If for some reason that doesn't suit your purposes either, write factory functions.